# GET works in POSTMAN but doesn't return anything when hosted

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

My .NET Core Web API is designed to store and fetch documents.

This is what my `GET` method looks like

```
     [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(int visitorId, string documentType)
    {
        var model = _service.GetDocumentByVisitorId(visitorId, documentType);
        return Ok(new ApiOkResponse(model));
    }
```

This is what my GetDocumentByVisitorId looks like -

```
    public VisitorDocumentViewModel GetDocumentByVisitorId(int visitorId, 
    string DocumentType)
    {
    var visitorDocCollection = _uow.Repository<VisitorDocuments>().GetAll();
    var docTypesCollection = _uow.Repository<DocumentType>().GetAll();

    var getVisitorDocument = (from visitorDocuments in visitorDocCollection
                          join documentTypes in docTypesCollection
                          on visitorDocuments.DocumentTypeId equals documentTypes.DocumentTypeId
                          where documentTypes.DocumentTypeName == documentType && visitorDocuments.VisitorId == visitorId
                          select visitorDocuments).FirstOrDefault();

return _mapper.Map<VisitorDocuments, VisitorDocumentViewModel>(getVisitorDocument);
```

}

VisitorDocumentViewModel exactly points to all the fields on my database.

When I run it locally, it return the desired result

This is what my url looks like -
`http://localhost:1316/api/ves/Document?visitorId=123&DocumentType=Photograph`

I have hosted my service and when I try to fetch the result, it doesn't return anything. Says page not found.

This is what my hosted url looks like -
`http://192.xxx.xxx.xx:9045/api/ves/Document?visitorId=123&DocumentType=Passport`

Browser says -

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)"

The same works on my local. Am I missing something?
Is more information needed?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? My first thought is that you may have some code that returns a 404 if your querystring params don't point to actual things (visitor, documentType).

Comment: @agileMike - Added relevant code

Comment: Do you have any [RoutePrefix] annotations at the top of your class? Or an [Authorize] attribute? I've seen the same issue when authorization is required it will try to redirect to the Login page and get a 404 for that. How are you doing the GET? Are you using Postman (and are you sure you've selected GET and not POST)?

Comment: I am currently not using any annotations. No authorization is implemented as of now. I am using postman for GET. It is retrieving the result locally, but is failing on the server. Any chance this might be a hosting issue?

Comment: What hosting are you using?  I'd try it with a routePrefix annotation like this: [RoutePrefix("api/Document")]

Comment: Another thing you might consider is installing a package called Swashbuckle. It will provide an interface documenting all your api methods. Perhaps the routing is different on the hosting and maybe that will help you to see it better.